# Deadline exceeded on App Engine Java blob delete

Tags: java, google-app-engine, blobstore

We have a rather elaborate App Engine Java application that works heavily with the blob store. For some reason one user (this was working for other users) getting timeout errors with his upload code (which deletes a few old blob's lying around). It doesn't delete many blob's (no more than 10) so I'm not sure what happened but he was able to reproduce this issue consistently several times until suddenly the issue resolved itself...

My concern is that it will start cropping up for other users in the future, I'd rather not cleanup the blobs than have a failure.

I'll probably change our architecture in the future to just work with a background cron job to seek out blobs that aren't referenced by anyone and delete them, but I'd be happy if someone can shed light on this issue.

```
Uncaught exception from servlet
com.google.apphosting.api.DeadlineExceededException: This request (7e6f710cb810ed92) started at 2012/11/27 08:59:54.585 UTC and was still executing at 2012/11/27 09:00:54.028 UTC.
    at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.parkNanos(LockSupport.java:226)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.doAcquireSharedNanos(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:1037)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.tryAcquireSharedNanos(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:1326)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture$Sync.get(AbstractFuture.java:275)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.get(AbstractFuture.java:96)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.TimedFuture.get(TimedFuture.java:55)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.ForwardingFuture.get(ForwardingFuture.java:69)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.ApiProxyImpl.doSyncCall(ApiProxyImpl.java:212)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.ApiProxyImpl.access$000(ApiProxyImpl.java:66)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.ApiProxyImpl$1.run(ApiProxyImpl.java:183)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.ApiProxyImpl$1.run(ApiProxyImpl.java:180)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.ApiProxyImpl.makeSyncCall(ApiProxyImpl.java:180)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.ApiProxyImpl.makeSyncCall(ApiProxyImpl.java:66)
    at com.google.apphosting.api.ApiProxy.makeSyncCall(ApiProxy.java:107)
    at com.google.apphosting.api.ApiProxy.makeSyncCall(ApiProxy.java:56)
    at com.google.appengine.api.blobstore.BlobstoreServiceImpl.delete(BlobstoreServiceImpl.java:125)
```

Answer (score 2):

The exception that you are facing is the `DeadlineExceededException`. It seems that you have invoked your code via a HTTP Request or maybe inside of web application hosted on Google App Engine.

All HTTP Requests are limited to 60 seconds of time to complete their work and return. If not, App Engine throws this exception. In short, when an application is called to serve a web request, it must issue a response within 60 seconds.

This is not the case with Cron Jobs, which have a time limit of 10 minutes before they too receive a `DeadlineExceededException`.

So, the behaviour that you are facing is normal and is controlled by App Engine. I suggest that you work around this by either moving this work to Cron Jobs, because:

- You will get 10 minutes to complete your work
- In case, even 10 minutes are not enough, you might want to catch the `DeadlineExceededException` and then recreate another task with a parameter that will instruct the Cron Job to take off from where it was last.

If none of the above meet your criteria, try exploring [Backends](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/backends/overview) in AppEngine which have no limits.

Comment: Perhaps I didn't phrase the question properly. I understand exactly the exception (notice my background cron job comment at the end), the problem is that all I'm doing is deleting a couple of blobs. Why is that taking more than 60 seconds? I understand co-located data center concepts, but shouldn't the app engine environment hide these things from us?

Comment: Not sure what could be causing the execution to take more than 60 seconds? The only thing could be if the code is still waiting on something, etc. But as you said, it works at times. Sorry - can't be of much help on that. Maybe someone from the AppEngine team could throw some light.